# d3 fitExtent function not mapping GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to map the geojson linked below, but i am having trouble with the projection. When i try to pass the GeoJSON feature collection into fitExtent, no map appears (no paths are drawn).

PS; 
I have used console log to break down each part of the code and everything seems fine i.e i have tested the file without the fitExtent function using regular scale and translate on the projection.

code snippet

```
let boroughProjection = d3.geoMercator().fitExtent(
          [
            [0, 0],
            [width, height],
          ],
          geojson
        );

let boroughPath = d3.geoPath().projection(boroughProjection);

let boroughMap = this.mapCanvasB
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(geojson)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "borough")
          .attr("d", boroughPath)
          .style("fill", "gray")
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("stroke-width", "0.4")
```

Link to GeoJSON https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackmad/neighborhoods/master/london.geojson

Comment: Does it work if you use `.data(geojson.features)` instead of `.data(geojson)`?

Comment: Yes geojson.features worked, though i am not sure why because i have a variable defined as geojson.features and when i used this in the data function, it did not work ( i got path error stating d expected numbers but got "NaN" instead ).